# Protobuf compiler for scala: ScalaPB

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf compiler from this: https://scalapb.github.io/

I followed the instructions to add plugins and lib dependencies.
But every time I put this code in:

```
PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
)
```

I always get an error saying scalapb is not found. 
I'm not sure where I can import this?

Thanks! Any help really appreciated!

Comment: You may want to show a little bit more of your build.sbt so one can try and help you.

Comment: In build.sbt, I basically put addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.6")

libraryDependencies += "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.6.0-pre3"   and then PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
)    But every time when sbt loads, it just says scalapb not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put these two lines in `project/scalapb.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.6")

libraryDependencies += "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.6.0-pre3"
```

and then this on your `build.sbt`:

```
PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
)
```

Should just make it work.